# How to retrieve data from a table row by row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table in sql server database as shown below,

```
           id   |  Labels
           -----+----------------
            1   |  MyHeaderLabel
            2   |  MyFooterLabel
            3   |  MyDescirption


Label1.text = firstrow(MyHeaderLabel)
Label2.text = secondrow(MyFooterLabel)
```

is there anyway to achieve it like this.

I am going to use stored procedure to retrieve them. Should I use data reader to get these value

Comment: Yes but make sure you put the using statements around the connection and data reader. And as far as sorting is concerned, do it server side in the query.

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with that data on the client application

Comment: I am going to show them in label.

Comment: If you have just three label (more or less) to read and set at page load then a SqlDataReader is the right class to use

Comment: it usually give error when i use dr.GetString(0)..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DataReader is a good option.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionStringHere))    
{

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(YourSQLQuery, conn);

     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while(dr.Read())      
     {

       Label1.Text = dr[1].ToString();

       // This is just an example. You can do whatever you want. :)

     }

}
```

I maybe wrong. So, feel free to correct me. ;)

Comment: if i get more data , i would do dr[2].tostring(); and so on ...right ?

Comment: dr[i] indicates the data in the ith column. For example, dr[0] indicates the data in the 1st column, dr[1] is 2nd column and so on. 
So, according to the code above, during the first iteration of the while loop, the first row in the 2nd column(dr[1]) is retrieved. During the second iteration, the second row is retrieved and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i solved my question

It takes the rows in order

```
Label1.Text = (dr.Read()) ? dr["Promts"].ToString() : "";

Label2.Text = (dr.Read()) ? dr["Promts"].ToString() : "";
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection_string"))
{
   cn.Open();
   using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("selest * from table_name",cn))
   {
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       adapter.Fill(table);
       foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
       {
           //get column data for a row using row["column_name"].ToString()
       }
   }
}
```